# Is there a way to *directly* cast a float to an integer in Java

Tags: java, math

In order to take advantage of some low-level math function approximation hacks, I would like to directly cast the four bytes of a float to an integer. Note that this is not the same as a regular Java cast, and I understand that this will not be the same number. I just want to interpret those four bytes as an integer instead of a float. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: like converting 12.90 to ? or 12.45 to ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes: [`Float.floatToIntBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits-float-).

Note however that this will return an integer as read in MSB (which is what Java does for all integer primitive types; floating point primitive types use base 2 IEEE 754, like the vast majority of existing computer programming languages). If you want LSB, you'll have to go through a `ByteBuffer` (and [set its byte order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order-java.nio.ByteOrder-); big endian by default).

Note that there is also [`Float.floatToRawIntBits()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits-float-). And that the `Double` class has equivalent methods (though they use `long`s instead, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for `floatToIntBits(float value)`?

> Returns a representation of the specified floating-point value
>   according to the IEEE 754 floating-point "single format" bit layout.

Then you can manipulate the bits as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use ByteBuffer methods putFloat() and getInt() ;-)

Comment: That works too, however you need to manipulate the offset before you read back!

Comment: @fge yes, this is true, i wanted to provide just hint how to solve problem or where to start, it is allways better when questioner compose the solution himself from hints than by copy pasting the whole provided  solution without actually understanding what it does.